# How can I convert a Daisy-formatted ebook to epub?

Tags: ebook, epub

I own a Kobo Touch, and there are some books available online in the Daisy format that I'd like to read on my Kobo.

The book is also available in PDF format, but I'd much rather have it in epub form. 
What can I do about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) is a free and open source e-book library management application developed by users of e-books for users of e-books. It has a cornucopia of features divided into the following main categories:

- Library Management
- **E-book conversion**
- Syncing to e-book reader devices
- Downloading news from the web and converting it into e-book form
- Comprehensive e-book viewer
- Content server for online access to your book collection

*(For Windows, OSX and linux)*